# Hacer consulta en BDD pgadmin4 para cumplir una función especifica SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mysqli, pgadmin

La pregunta que quiero resolver es **Cree una consulta que muestre la hora actual si el nombre contiene seis caracteres
y la hora actual más una hora en otros casos**

Lo que hice y no funciono es

```
SELECT nombre, 
IF(LENGHT(nombre) = 6,CURRENT_TIME,ADDTIME(CURRENT_TIME,'1:00:00)) AS horario 
FROM persona;
```

Comment: Para empezar, necesitas aclarar cual manejador de base de datos usas. Parece PostgreSQL, pero usas etiquetas de mysql y sql server. Los tres manejadores tienen sintaxis distinta.

Comment: Es PostgreSQL lo que uso

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas revisar la sintaxis del lenguaje que estás utilizando. La lógica es correcta, pero la forma de escribirlo no lo es.

```
SELECT nombre, 
       CASE WHEN LENGHT(nombre) = 6 THEN CURRENT_TIME + '1 hour'::interval ELSE CURRENT_TIME END AS horario
FROM persona;
```